# Can Spring access-denied-handler refer to popup?

Tags: java, spring-security

I am working with Spring Security 3.1.x and have implemented method annotation securities. As I want, when I perform a certain action while being logged in as a used that doesn't have the rights, I get a 403 acces is denied in my console! Perfect!

Now I would like to catch this 403, and give the user a popup with a custom message. I don't want to redirect users to a page saying that they have no rights.

Is there any way the access-denied-handler of Spring can take care of a popup? Or can it only redirect to another page? Maybe there are other options for me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box Spring Security will simply send a 403 as an error. Most containers will provide a default error page for the 403 status and render an HTML page. There is no redirect in this instance it is a forward.

It sounds as though you are using JavaScript, if so you can detect if the HTTP Status is a 403 and then display your custom message. If you were using JQuery it would look something like this

```
   $(document).ajaxError(function( event, jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    if (jqxhr.status == 403 ) {
      // output custom error
    } else {
      // ...other errors...
    }
  });
```

You can do whatever you want in a custom AccessDeniedHandler so long as it provides the completed response. In fact, you can specify an error-page forward to another URL so that you could process the URL with a Spring MVC (or other type of) controller if you wanted. If you are using the XML namespace, this can be done with something like this:

```
<http>
    <!-- ... -->

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
</http>
```

You can then process the /403 URL anyway you like. For example, if you want to set the status and provide an error message you could create a Spring MVC controller that does something like this:

```
@Controller
public class ErrorsController {

    @RequestMapping("/403")
    public void forbidden(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
       response.getWritter().write("You do not have permission to perform this operation");
    }
}
```

Your JavaScript could then catch the 403 and then use the body of the response to display the message. Of course, you could also format the response to be JSON if you wanted too.

Comment: This is exactly it for me. Thanks a lot. The accesDeniedHandler implementation did indeed an awesome job. I actually let the accessDeniedHandler throw up a 403 HTTP status. 

Like you said, I catched it with javascript and from there a popup was a lot easier! Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

Usually the error pages are generated by your appllication server.
In your web.xml you can define custom error pages for different error codes.
Your web application server will then display the custom error page instead of the original one.

Paste this in your web.xml file

```
<error-page>
<error-code>403</error-code>
<location>/youraccessdeniedpage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Furthermore, add an intercept-url tag your spring security such that anybody can see the error page

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/youraccessdeniedpage.jsp" access="permitAll"/>
```

In the custom error page you can display anything you want, including popups and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the help, although it would still redirect me to another page (youraccessdeniedpage.jsp). I fixed it by throwing a 403 HTTP Status and catching it with JavaScript :)

Answer (score 1):

To perform your access denied logic you may implement AccessDeniedHandler. This is not exactly that you want. It has handle method with HttpServletResponse object. So you may write any message you want or redirect to anther page. But the main problem is that you must perform an http request and load another page. This is the way in which Spring Security works. 
However if you really want to do this you may try to perform an ajax request and to check if it returns 403 page.

Comment: Yes this is really good, thanks a lot! I actually did it this way now! I'm sorry I can't vote up correct answer for both the answers that were given! Thanks a lot for the help though!! :)